# React native android signed release build apk crashing on device

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle, apk

My react-native debug build works totally fine on the device but the release and signed build crash when trying to open after installing. I was trying to get logs from `ADB locate and it's outputting saying start the metro server.

```
12-02 09:44:27.377  4062  4240 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
12-02 09:44:27.377  4062  4240 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.(appId), PID: 4062
12-02 09:44:27.377  4062  4240 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
12-02 09:44:27.377  4062  4240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
12-02 09:44:27.377  4062  4240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:234)
12-02 09:44:27.377  4062  4240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
12-02 09:44:27.377  4062  4240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:258)
12-02 09:44:27.377  4062  4240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1293)
12-02 09:44:27.377  4062  4240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:131)
12-02 09:44:27.377  4062  4240 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1016)
12-02 09:44:27.377  4062  4240 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
12-02 11:59:38.982 13812 14329 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
12-02 11:59:38.982 13812 14329 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.com.(appId), PID: 13812
```

Previous builds worked fine and I had to do some changes with the Gradle versions.

This is my

> build.Gradle

versions

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        // Added for netinfo
         androidXCore = "1.0.2"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

This is my

> gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.3-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

keystore files are fine and Iam using Microsoft AppCenter to distribute builds and also codepush.

signing is handled by build.gradle file configs.

When i run `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/`

its outputting

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePbnK.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like it is a debug build instead of release build. Make sure you follow [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) steps.

Comment: @Ravi It is actually handled by AppCenter when we are building. They have the option to select if we want a release or a debug build

Comment: `android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle` Is this file exist in your code?

Comment: @Kailash no it doesn't. should I manually create it?

Comment: yes create manually.

Comment: Then how are you creating release build ? Using Android Studio or command line ? @PasanInduwara

Comment: @Kailash Iam using AppCenter to create builds. creating index.android.bundle also didn't work.

Showing an error like this now in logcat

12-03 07:43:42.487 16404 16505 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_js
12-03 07:43:42.487 16404 16505 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.{appId}, PID: 16404
12-03 07:43:42.487 16404 16505 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly

Comment: @PasanInduwara execute this command on your project root directory  `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/`

Then push your code and start build on AppCenter, make sure you correctly setup environment for AppCenter.

Comment: @Kailash there is an error showing 

error SyntaxError: /Users/user/Documents/ReactNative/MobileModo/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/index.ts: Unexpected token (7:12)

Comment: Can you add screenshot ?

Comment: @Kailash I have updated the question with it

Comment: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/1374 Please try updating @babel/core and @babel/runtime dependencies